# How to write "This is" in Kanji?

Tags: kanji

I get これは in hiragana, but I need 2 kanji characters to be able to write a short sentence "This is"
for example:
"This is"  my home
"This is" can be applied to any of my properties

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's not possible at least in Japanese.

Comment: 這是 (or 这是) in Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

There is no kanji for the particle は (unless you are writing [Man'yōgana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man%27y%C5%8Dgana) perhaps).

One might ask why there have to be exactly two characters, and why they have to be kanji? If you absolutely must have the text be the width of two characters, might I suggest XXです?

Comment: So if I forget the hiragana, and want to translate "This is" directly from English in Kanji, which characters could I use?

Comment: Some words (and certainly most Japanese particles) do not have kanji, so your request is hard to satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be all kanji? I might not fully understand the motivation but if you just want to have it as a prefix and the length to be 2 characters, 此は can fit.

此方, read "kochira" (こちら), can fit, but some may not understand the intention because it lacks は/が.

Comment: It has to be all Kanji ...

Comment: @JNPfeiffer Then Japanese is probably the wrong language to choose.

Comment: So if I want the phonetic of TIS  and IS which Kanji characters I should use ? This is for an artistic project.

Comment: @JNPfeiffer I think you're severely understanding how Japanese writing works. If I asked you to find me two letters of the English alphabet that sound like "fish", would you be able to?

Comment: @JNPfeiffer Japanese kanji are not phonograms but [ideograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideogram). They are not used to represent arbitrary sounds. Your question is essentially no different than asking "how to write the sound of 'this is' using two Arabic numerals (1, 2, ...) or zodiac symbols (♍︎, ♒︎, ...)". Just as Arabic numerals cannot represent the sound of ordinary English words, kanji are not used to represent the pronunciation of arbitrary words. We use kana for that purpose.